# jQuery - Checkboxes are not updating text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently returning a couple of texts based on which checkboxes being checked. I've added a single checkbox to automatically check all the countries but that doesn't return any text in return. Can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code and fiddle:

HTML

```
<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkCountries" /> Check Countries</label></p>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Loads of checkboxes</legend>
  <p><label><input type="checkbox" value="1" /> USA</label></p>
  <p><label><input type="checkbox" value="2" /> Canada</label></p>
  <p><label><input type="checkbox" value="3" /> UK</label></p>
  <p><label><input type="checkbox" value="4" /> Spain</label></p>
  <p><label><input type="checkbox" value="10" /> Male</label></p>
  <p><label><input type="checkbox" value="11" /> Female</label></p>
</fieldset>
<div class="print"></div>
<div class="print2"></div>
<div class="print3"></div>
<div class="print4"></div>
<div class="print10"></div>
<div class="print11"></div>
```

And jQuery

```
$("#checkCountries").change(function() {
  $("input[value='1']").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
  $("input[value='2']").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
  $("input[value='3']").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
  $("input[value='4']").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.print').val($(this).is(':checked'));

  $('input[value="1"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).attr("checked", $('.print').text("USA is Checked"));
    } else {
      $('.print').empty();
    }
    $('.print').val($(this).is(':checked'));
  });
  $('input[value="2"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).attr("checked", $('.print2').text("Canada is Checked"));
    } else {
      $('.print2').empty();
    }
    $('.print2').val($(this).is(':checked'));
  });
  $('input[value="3"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).attr("checked", $('.print3').text("UK is Checked"));
    } else {
      $('.print3').empty();
    }
    $('.print3').val($(this).is(':checked'));
  });
  $('input[value="4"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).attr("checked", $('.print4').text("Spain is Checked"));
    } else {
      $('.print4').empty();
    }
    $('.print4').val($(this).is(':checked'));
  });
  $('input[value="10"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).attr("checked", $('.print10').text("Male is Checked"));
    } else {
      $('.print10').empty();
    }
    $('.print10').val($(this).is(':checked'));
  });
  $('input[value="11"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).attr("checked", $('.print11').text("Female is Checked"));
    } else {
      $('.print11').empty();
    }
    $('.print11').val($(this).is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gf28v9x5/3/

Comment: What you want to print in .print div, If you checked this <input type="checkbox" id="checkCountries" /> ?
If I am not wrong you want to print value this checkCountries checbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly trigger change event.

Note that change event only triggers by user actions on that particular element.

What I did,

Just triggered when changing `check/uncheck`

```
$("input[value='1']").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).trigger('change');
```

Like  https://jsfiddle.net/4ktbjwL2/1/

```js
$("#checkCountries").change(function () {
    $("input[value='1']").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).trigger('change');
    $("input[value='2']").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).trigger('change');
    $("input[value='3']").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).trigger('change');
    $("input[value='4']").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).trigger('change');
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.print').val($(this).is(':checked'));
    
    $('input[value="1"]').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).attr("checked", $('.print').text("USA is Checked"));
        } else {
        $('.print').empty();
        }
        $('.print').val($(this).is(':checked'));        
    });
        $('input[value="2"]').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).attr("checked", $('.print2').text("Canada is Checked"));
        } else {
        $('.print2').empty();
        }
        $('.print2').val($(this).is(':checked'));        
    });
        $('input[value="3"]').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).attr("checked", $('.print3').text("UK is Checked"));
        } else {
        $('.print3').empty();
        }
        $('.print3').val($(this).is(':checked'));        
    });
        $('input[value="4"]').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).attr("checked", $('.print4').text("Spain is Checked"));
        } else {
        $('.print4').empty();
        }
        $('.print4').val($(this).is(':checked'));        
    });
        $('input[value="10"]').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).attr("checked", $('.print10').text("Male is Checked"));
        } else {
        $('.print10').empty();
        }
        $('.print10').val($(this).is(':checked'));        
    });
        $('input[value="11"]').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).attr("checked", $('.print11').text("Female is Checked"));
        } else {
        $('.print11').empty();
        }
        $('.print11').val($(this).is(':checked'));        
    });
});
```

```html
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkCountries"/> Check Countries</label></p>
    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Loads of checkboxes</legend>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" value="1" /> USA</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" value="2" /> Canada</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" value="3" /> UK</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" value="4" /> Spain</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" value="10" /> Male</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" value="11" /> Female</label></p>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="print"></div>
    <div class="print2"></div>
    <div class="print3"></div>
    <div class="print4"></div>
    <div class="print10"></div>
    <div class="print11"></div>
```

Comment: Nice! You rock! I will accept your answer in 3 minutes!

Answer (score 1):

I think the better approach is to have single code block defining the checkbox click handler dynamically for each of the checkboxes

I have created a fiddler like below

```
$('.chkCountry').change(function() {

        const val = $(this).val();
        const text = $(this).attr('data');
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('.print' + val).html(text + " is Checked");
        } else {
        $('.print' + val).html("");
        }

    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/muasif80/7wujn196/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can give the same class name to all country and print the text as below

I have created a fiddler like below:

```js
$("#checkCountries").change(function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('.chkcountery').prop('checked', true);
    $('.Text').html("USA is Checked<br/>Canada is Checked <br />UK is Checked <br /> Spain is Checked");
  }
  else {
    $('.chkcountery').prop('checked', false);
    $('.Text').text('');
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k391bhrg/9/

Comment: Thank you for suggestion